# How to connect ASP.NET Core Web API with SQL Server CE 3.5 database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, sql-server-ce-3.5

I added `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll` v3.5 in my ASP.NET Core Web API project, but I'm getting error while connecting to SQL Server CE database.

This is my code:

```
 private static string DbFilePath = @"C:\Git\Forecaster\DB\THSTaxPro.sdf";
        private static string DbPassword = "123567";
        private static string DbMaxSize = "4090";
        public static string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=" + DbFilePath + ";Password=" + DbPassword + ";Max Database Size=" + DbMaxSize + "";

        [Route("thsAdditionalincome")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<AdditionalIncome>> thsAdditionalincome(string accountid)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(_connectionString))
                {
                    var query = "select irs_account_id,income_alimony,income_alimony_taxpayer,income_alimony_spouse,income_child_support ,  income_child_support_taxpayer,income_child_support_spouse ,income_net_business, income_net_business_taxpayer, income_net_business_spouse , income_net_rental , income_net_rental_taxpayer , income_net_rental_spouse ,   income_pension ,  income_pension_taxpayer ,income_pension_spouse, income_interest_dividends , income_interest_dividends_taxpayer,income_interest_dividends_spouse, income_social_security,income_social_security_taxpayer,income_social_security_spouse,income_other_1,income_other_1_taxpayer,income_other_2,income_other_2_taxpayer,income_other_2_spouse from t_financial_analysis_individual  where IsDeleted=0 and irs_account_id=@accountid";
                    var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
                    parameters.Add("@accountid", accountid, DbType.String);

                    conn.Open();

                    var results = await conn.QueryAsync<AdditionalIncome>(query, param: new { accountid });

                    return results.ToList();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
            



        }
```

[image: This is my Code]

This is the error I am getting:

[image: This is The error i am getting]

Comment: Do not post text as pictures. Code, error messages, etc, should all be posted as text, formatted appropriately. If you do post a screenshot, don't show your entire screen when only part of it is relevant. The snipping tool built into Windows can select an arbitrary box so there's no excuse not to.

Comment: First of all - if at all, you should use SQL Server CE **v4.0** - 3.5 is beyond dead..... and even SQL Server CE 4.0 is no longer officially supported - I'd strongly recommend alternatives, like either SQL Server Express / LocalDB, or SQLite, if you need an "embedded" database system

Answer (score 0):

SQL CE is out of support. But there is a way you can use SQL CE 3.5 in asp.net core project.

Step1. Go to CE3.5 installation folder. Copy all .dll files except `system.data.sqlserverce.entity` to a new folder named `amd64` ,paste this folder to project root.

[image]

Step2. from private folder copy `system.data.sqlserverce.dll` to project root
[image]

You project root is like 
[image]

Step3. open .csproj add the following reference

```
    <ItemGroup>

        <Content Include="amd64\sqlceca35.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="amd64\sqlcecompact35.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="amd64\sqlceer35EN.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="amd64\sqlceme35.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="amd64\sqlceoledb35.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>  
        <Content Include="amd64\sqlceqp35.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="amd64\sqlcese35.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="System.Data.SqlServerCe">
            <HintPath>System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll</HintPath>
        </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
```

Step4.install nuget package`Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` latest version.

Now restart your project, SqlCeConnection will work.

All .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>

        <Content Include="amd64\sqlceca35.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="amd64\sqlcecompact35.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="amd64\sqlceer35EN.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="amd64\sqlceme35.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="amd64\sqlceoledb35.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>  
        <Content Include="amd64\sqlceqp35.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="amd64\sqlcese35.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="System.Data.SqlServerCe">
            <HintPath>System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll</HintPath>
        </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: I try above all activity but my code  given this error 


Unable to load DLL 'sqlceme35.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)

Comment: @RavindraSingh DId you install other sqlserverce related nuget package？If you have try remove them all.

Comment: nuget package i install list are 

1.Dapper
2.Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility
3.Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger

Comment: @RavindraSingh It's really strange, I referenced this blog with verstion 3.5 and also works well. You can check if there is anything help. https://erikej.github.io/sqlce/2020/08/17/netcore-sql-compact.html. I used .net6 for test.

Comment: this blog on 4.0. i upgrade 3.5 to 4.0 database working fine but i don't want to update my database because other related software not working after update

Comment: @RavindraSingh I paste all my working sample csproj at the end of answer, you can have a look.

Comment: @RavindraSingh Or maybe reinstall v3.5?https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5783  I didn't do any other steps.